# How to exempt selected characters from substitution in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have this text:

```
"1-1-1"
"1-1-2"
"1-1-3"
"1-2-1"
"1-2-2"
"1-2-3"
"1-3-1"
"1-3-2"
"1-3-3"
```

I want to insert `0` on every line after the second hyphen, turning `"1-1-1"` into `"1-1-01"`.

I tried substituting with `:%s/-\d"/-0\d/` but that turns `1-1-1` into `1-1-0d`.

How can I insert one symbol without changing the surrounding text?

Comment: For non-programming questions please use https://vi.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following replacement:

```
:%s/-\(\d+\)"$/-0\1"/
```

### Demo

The idea here is to match *and* capture the final digit in `\1`, then build the replacement using that capture group, with a prefixed zero.

Comment: This was 99% of the answer, thank you! Full explanation above.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to throw a different feature into the ring because I find it quite unique.  Vim regular expressions have two zero-width atoms to designate the start (`\zs`) and end (`\ze`) of the text to be considered a match.  You can use them in interesting ways, such as:

```
:%s/-\zs\ze\d"/0/
```

Which tells vim to replace the text between `\zs` and `\ze` (which happens to be empty here) with `0` if the rest of the regular expression matches.

Alternatively, using only `\ze`:

```
:%s/-\ze\d"/-0/
```

Which tells vim to replace `-` with `-0` when the original `-` is followed by a digit and a double quote.

See `:help \zs` and `:help \ze` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in normal mode you could place the cursor on the last hyphen of the first line and use:

```
<c-v>GA0<esc>
```

Explanation:

- `<c-v>`: Ctrl+v to enter block-visual mode
- `G`: extend visual selection until the end of the file
- `A0`: enter insert mode and put a `0`
- `<esc>`: Escape insert mode

More info in `:help v_b_A`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Biegeleisen for the answer!

The final RegEx was `:%s/-\(\d+\)"$/-0\1"/`

Basically his answer, except I had to escape each parenthesis with a backslash `\`

Breakdown: `:%s` + `/` + `-\(\d+\)"$` + `/` + `-0\1"` + `/`

- `:%s`: open substitute function for all lines in file
- `/`: Begin pattern to search for
- `-\(\d+\)"$`: search for all `-`, followed by one or more digits `\d+`, followed by the end of the line `$`

  - the parentheses `()` create a "capture group", and the backslashes `\` escape the parentheses so they aren't interpreted literally
- `/`: End pattern / Begin substitute string
- `-0\1"`: Substitute a hyphen(`-0`) followed by "capture group #1" (`\1`), followed by a quotation `"`

  - "capture group 1" is `\d+`; any pre-existing digits
  - since there is only one capture group, it's default number is 1
- `/`: End expression

Comment: Please don't use answers to respond or thank people.  Answers are specifically for answers. Summarizing isn't necessary unless you intend that you'll select the answer as the appropriate one. By summarizing what you did you can inadvertently confuse others as to which was the correct solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can be more simple:

```
:%s/\d\+"/0&

\d\+" ................ gets the last number and the close quote
0 .................... the wanted zero
& .................... let's get back the searched pattern
```

Another easy solution:

```
:%norm 2f-a0

% ................... whole file
norm ................ normal mode
2f- ................. jump to the second dash "-"
a ................... start insert on append mode
0 ................... the character we want insert
```